# How to call JavaScript functions from SPA Durandal application using a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, single-page-application, durandal

I have a `SAP Durandal` application and I'm wondering if its possible use some function already build on ~\App\shell\index.js or any other `JS` file on my project from `Android Studio` `WebView`.

Comment: you should be able to.  You do it using requirejs and importing the module.

Comment: I'll sure try it. tks